# add New Path to svg on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am hovering over an svg and want to add a shape on a specific part that I hover over.

I have tried the following code by appending the `path` shape to the path on the svg that was hovered over but this doesn't work. Hopefully the code below will make clearer the issue I am having. if anymore details are required please let me know.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.city', function(e) {
  $(this).append('<path class="st0" d="M59.4,0H10.6h-0.5c-5.7,0-12,5.7-9.6,11.7c1.4,3.6,3.9,7.2,5.8,10.7c1.2,2.2,2.4,4.3,3.5,6.5h0.4l3.5-6.3c1.3-2.3,2.8-4.6,4-7h41.6c4.3,0,7.8-3.5,7.8-7.8l0,0C67.1,3.5,63.7,0,59.4,0z"/>')
  console.log(this)
});
```

`this` then looks like this:

```
<path class="city" d="M653.3,209.8c3.2,0,6.2,3.2,4.9,6.4c-0.8,1.8-2,3.6-3,5.4c-0.6,1.1-1.2,2.2-1.8,3.3h-0.2   c-0.6-1.2-1.2-2.2-1.9-3.4c-1-1.8-2.3-3.7-3-5.6C647.1,212.7,650.3,209.8,653.3,209.8"><path class="st0" d="M59.4,0H10.6h-0.5c-5.7,0-12,5.7-9.6,11.7c1.4,3.6,3.9,7.2,5.8,10.7c1.2,2.2,2.4,4.3,3.5,6.5h0.4l3.5-6.3c1.3-2.3,2.8-4.6,4-7h41.6c4.3,0,7.8-3.5,7.8-7.8l0,0C67.1,3.5,63.7,0,59.4,0z"></path><path class="st0" d="M59.4,0H10.6h-0.5c-5.7,0-12,5.7-9.6,11.7c1.4,3.6,3.9,7.2,5.8,10.7c1.2,2.2,2.4,4.3,3.5,6.5h0.4l3.5-6.3c1.3-2.3,2.8-4.6,4-7h41.6c4.3,0,7.8-3.5,7.8-7.8l0,0C67.1,3.5,63.7,0,59.4,0z"></path></path>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to have two paths and then show one and hide the other on hover rather than modifying the existing path. You could do that in CSS.

Comment: @RobertLongson the thing is that this repeats itself around 50 times, but is not included in the svg. make sense? the asset has been provided by the designer, but they have not provided the hover state in the svg

Comment: So why not add it to the SVG?

Comment: @RobertLongson thats what i was thinking, but a colleague thought this way would be better. so you think changing the svg manually is a better approach?